# gunicorn issue - file is not executable

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to execute gunicorn using supervisorctl. Here is the supervisor config file:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/mlino/flights
command=/home/mlino/.local/bin/python3 main.py run_gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock
numprocs=3
user=mlino
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
stderr_logfile=/var/log/flights/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flights/gunicorn.out.log
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
(venv) mlino@server1:~/flights$ sudo supervisorctl start gunicorn
[sudo] password for mlino:
gunicorn: ERROR (file is not executable)
(venv) mlino@server1:~/flights$
```

I've tried other config also, but with the same error message: ERROR (file is not executable). Any help would be great.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you verify whether `/home/mlino/.local/bin/python3` is indeed executable for user `mlino`? Check owner and permissions.

Comment: Hi @CherryDT. Yes, it is. `
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mlino mlino 4676064 Sep  1 13:20 python3
`